# Can I add a id to a image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to `id` a picture in HTML to edit it in CSS, but it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```css
#1{
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5492f3e3e4b0c40c56916924/t/586590b3d1758e4aacbf4aa4/1483051196842/?format=1500w" id="1"/>
```

But the picture isn't formatted the way I wanted to to be.
So do I need to add the code into the HTML itself or what do I need to do?

Comment: Where did you style it with CSS?

Comment: id must start with alphabetical char, like as `id='img1'` for img tag and refer it in css: `#img1`

Answer (score 2):

You have already defined the id attribute id="1", but this id value does not qualify the following criteria.

**Must contain at least one character**

Read [the HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

But also if you are on HTML 4 [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) says:

**ID  must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").**

Try with

```css
#myimage
{
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5492f3e3e4b0c40c56916924/t/586590b3d1758e4aacbf4aa4/1483051196842/?format=1500w" id="myimage"/>
```

Comment: @downvoter : care to give a reason as well?

Comment: I assume you were downvoted because "1" is a character per the definition used for the word "character".

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used a number. Switch to something like "one" instead.

> Tempted to use something like "1800number_box" for a ID? Don't. Because it won't work. Class identifiers are allowed to start with a number, but ID identifiers are not.

*[ID’s Cannot Start With a Number](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)*

Answer (score 0):

If you will be reusing this style on any other images, you should style it by class instead.

```
<img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5492f3e3e4b0c40c56916924/t/586590b3d1758e4aacbf4aa4/1483051196842/?format=1500w" class="some-style"/>
```

Then:

```css
.some-style {
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

Now you can use this same styling over and over without having to add more to your CSS file, since there can only be one `id` element per page, but you can have as many elements as you want with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are learning CSS, you would most probably be looking for these two errors:

- Your id does not start with numbers: change `id = 1` to `id="one"`
- The second possible error is that you are not putting the CSS in the correct area. Put the CSS in `<style></style>` tags in the `<head></head>`

For external stylesheets, remember to add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The MDN says:

> **Note**: Using characters except ASCII letters and digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in
>   HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID
>   should start with a letter for compatibility.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

[HTML 4.01 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

However, [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) and the [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) allows IDs start with digits:

> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
>   particular, *IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit*, start
>   with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.

So I would suggest to stick to the MDN recommendation: For compatibility reasons, don't start your ID or name with a digit. Instead `id="1"`, use something like `id="img1"`.

Comment: May I ask why my answer was downvoted just a few seconds after I posted it? It's not even possible to read that fast...

Comment: I've seen a lot of downvotes by other people posting answers. That shouldn't really be allowed - why would you be allowed to post an answer and be able to downvote someone else's answer to the same question?

Comment: Hmm? The only vote I made here was for Benio's answer (because it is quite good and I didn't knew it) - and it was an upvote.

Comment: I'm saying it's probably someone else who answered who downvoted you to make their answer more likely to be chosen.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```css
#myimage, img.myimage {
        border-width: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        }
```

```html
    <img id="myimage" class="myimage" src="https://pp.vk.me/c837520/v837520867/16752/q1EHBfmdpgQ.jpg">
```

**Also you can try this way :**

```html
<img id="myimage" class="myimage" src="https://pp.vk.me/c837520/v837520867/16752/q1EHBfmdpgQ.jpg" style="border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; width: 25%; height: 25%;">
```